# Need Help for WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, tableview, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

I am using WKInterfaceTable. In Table's Group I have label with heigth set dynamic. When Table's Group set height sizeToFit Content. ScrollToRowAtIndex method is not working properly.

Comment: Can you add some code to show what you are doing? then people have a better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: You are using `heigth` and `height` is that the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should not place a Table inside a Group, as it will cause the issues you are experiencing.
[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/):

> Don’t embed tables inside groups. Tables resize dynamically based on
>   the number of rows they contain; they ignore height restrictions
>   placed on them by groups.

Answer (score 0):

According to apples documentation you should use ScrollToRowAtIndex.
"Table's Group set height sizeToFit Content" its not the problem. I faced the same issue and it seems like a bug, but with dispatch_async it worked just fine.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{  
    [self.table scrollToRowAtIndex:yourRowHere];  
});
```